# Get Mac unique identifier number (ex.: serial number) in 64-bits

Tags: macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

how can i retrieve in Cocoa, Mac unique identifier, for ex.: serial number in 64-bit mode ?

I've followed couple articles but they were intended for 32-bit mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this article ["How to get hardware and network info"](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?HowToGetHardwareAndNetworkInfo)

If you are having trouble with the 64bit architecture - or your app simply has to be a 64bit app - consider moving the IO part to a helper utility and access it using distributed objects.

Have a look at [Creating XPC Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html)

Comment: sure i did, but as i mentioned it's intended for 32bit apps.

Comment: What does the compiler say when you implement the `computerSerialNumber` method? I've implemented an apple remote wrapper using IOKit and never run into 64bit issues.

Comment: `"_IOMasterPort"` (...)
`"_IORegistryGetRootEntry"` (...)
`"_IORegistryEntrySearchCFProperty"` (...)

`ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: What i needed after flowing article from CocoaDev was to import `IOKit.framework` to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to execute:

ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber | awk '{print $4}'